# auto exclude folders / files with a certain name from vs2017 solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask this but there have been a lot of visual studio questions in the past here.

I am currently creating a lot of npm packages in a solution and as part of the package, I have to create a package.json file.

Once I save the file, it creates a node_modules folder and downloads all the dependent npm packages to it.  Now I have got azure dev ops to ignore these files so they aren't checked in by adding the node modules folder to the list of ignored folder names, but I also want to exclude them from my project so that it doesn't lock my computer every time it tries to write all the file names in to the .proj file.

Is there a way to automatically tell the project or solution to auto exclude this folder - like a solution ignore file I can add the name to?

Or is there an option somewhere that folders that aren't created through vs, aren't automatically added to the project - this is how my earlier versions of vs worked - new folders not created through vs would have to be manually included if you wanted them in the project / solution

Comment: One of the workarounds, is to mark the folder as hidden https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Oct/30/Excluding-the-nodemodules-Folder-in-Visual-Studio-WebSite-Projects

Comment: hmmm, by that time though it's already been added to the project and locked my computer as it is writing to the proj file so I may as well just right click and exclude from solution at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is due to the project type that I used when creating the project - I created it as a .net core project and that seems to add files by default and only exclude them if you tell it to, if I change this back to a .net standard project, it works as I would expect - only includes files you drag into the project or tell it to include